# Git-svn merging and committing branches

Tags: git, git-svn

I have been using git-svn lately to manage an old svn repository through git.

I have recently been working in a branch that i created like this:
`git checkout -b local-branch svn-branch`

I have then since been working in that branch and commiting back to the svn-branch using:
`git svn dcommit`

Now that it's time to merge the local-branch back to master i tried to do the following:
`git checkout master`
`git merge local-branch`

So far, so good. Now i want to commit the merge back to subversion so i try this:
`git svn dcommit`

However, now my master is committing back to the svn-branch branch and not the trunk as i would have expected. Is there something i missed or is this kind of merging just not recommended to merge between svn branches like this?

As a side note, i instead did the merging through svn, but i would like to avoid having to use svn as much as possible. What is the preferred way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git svn dcommit` always sends changes to the url specified in git-svn-id signature that is the latest by first-parent chain of commits in HEAD's history.

I suppose, your merge was fast-forwarded (i.e. master reference was reachable from local-branch/svn-branch), so it was just set to local-branch by "git merge" instead of merge commit creation.

As a recommendation always use --no-ff option with "git merge" because Subversion has no such concept as fast-forward merge. (you can set this option (`merge.ff=true`) as default in [config](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)  [ or `branch.master.mergeoptions` to  "--no-ff" for Git < 1.7.6] but note that  "git pull" will become non-fast-forward too if you use more than 1 remote)

And in order to avoid SVN and/or git-svn: if you have an access to your repository server, you may have a look at [SubGit](http://subgit.com) project that provides pure Git (not git-svn) interface to Subversion. Even in the case of SubGit --no-ff option is strongly recommended because fast-forward merge (and fast-forward rebase) cannot be distinguished from branch removal and recreation from another commit (this is true for any Git<->SVN translation tool).

But maybe any other reason (I don't know any other) caused "git-svn-id" with branch URL (instead of trunk URL) in the latest commit message. Anyway make sure that master points to a correct commit.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it out by adding a new file in my branch, and then merged it back into the master with `git merge local-branch --no-ff` and then commit the master to svn with `git svn dcommit` and this time it committed to trunk.